# convert decrypt method into sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, encryption

I am trying to replicate an encrypt function written in C# but do it in SQL Server.

Here is the method in C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
        var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

        byte[] cipherTextBytes;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're choosing a complicated solution!

Can you workaround it by invoking your C# encryption thru a web service from the SQL? like this [example](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/forums/microsoft-data-platform/sql-server-bi/9/sql-programming-calling-the-web-service-thru-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL Server Extended Stored Procedures.  Using which you can call your C# methods from within SQL Server. Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653.aspx this URL.

Rewriting C# code in SQL Server is complicated, better to use Extended SP's.